# Refresh template after ajax delete

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, google-app-engine, templates

I have a table with some to-do tasks and I want to be able to remove tasks through ajax but I do not know how to refresh my table after deleting.

I already am able to delete a task but I do not see the task removed until i refresh the page. I am sending some foo message to the template and I can see it but what I dont know is how to send the result of my query again and send a bunch of tasks to the template and show them in the table

this is my code

controller

```
    class Delete(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    string_id = self.request.get("task")[12:28]
    task_key = ndb.Key('Task', int(string_id))
    task_key.delete()

    session = Session(self.request)
    user = User.get_by_id(session.email)
    userkey=user.key
    tasks=Task.query(Task.author==userkey)

    response_data = {'message' : 'foo'}

    self.response.out.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/json'
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response_data))
    return

    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @login_required
    def get(self):
    session = Session(self.request)
    user = User.get_by_id(session.email)
    userkey=user.key
    tasks=Task.query(Task.author==userkey)

    template_values = {
        'tasks': tasks
    }

    template = 'index.html'
    render_template(self,template,template_values)
```

javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.delete-button').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/delete',
  data: $('#delete-form').serialize(),
  success: showData,
  error: null
});
return false;
}); 

})

function showData(data){
    $('#prueba').html(data.message)
 }
```

template

```
 <table >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Descripcion</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ task.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ task.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ task.date|datetime }}</td>
      <td>{{ task.status }}</td>
      <td> 
        <form action="#" id="delete-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="task"  value="{{task.key}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="delete-button">
        </form> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tbody>
  </table> 
   <div id="prueba"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just refresh the page or after deleting in ajax make a Jquery function which will dynamically remove this object from your view. This are only two options you have ;)

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/delete',
  data: $('#delete-form').serialize(),
  success: showData,
  error: null
}, function() {
                 Your removing function 
                });
```

In your removing function you have to just simply find this object which you want to remove and remove it, for example:

```
$(#ObjectName).parents("li:first").remove();
```

Comment: It might be a valid option but I'd rather to refresh the query and send it again to the template. I do not know if it's possible but I guess it is as in other frameworks like rails.

Comment: @sarts There's no added bonus in refreshing the entire query besides a lot more work. It's possible, if you build another request, send it in json and have the current page layer it out through an ajax request, then after every delete tell it to run that ajax again. But that's an extremely long way that eventually is the same as simply deleting